# Print footer on every printed page from website, across all browsers (Chrome)

Tags: css

Dear all, I tried CSS Position: Fixed Property but it does work properly on Firefox and IE(hack for IE6), but it's not working at all for Chrome. I thought Chrome being the latest  will support it very easily but still it isn't. I Tried out <thead>,<tfoot><tbody> again works in IE and Firefox, but problematic in Chrome. Please any one have an alternate solution to it.

Comment: Hi there. I just ran into this problem, too. Seems like chrome handles the print position:fixed different than all the others. Damn... Will dig deeper into this one.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

This is the code i use. Note I am setting both html and body height to 100%.

```
@media print {
  html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem at all. It will make the footer be printed on the last page only. It even brakes it in the browsers that worked with position fixed.

Answer (score 18):

It seems like Chrome[webkit] has different way of handling position:fixed in print stylesheets than the rest of the browsers.

So the current answer to this question is:
There is no adequate solution for this in Chrome.

Whereas FF and IE render it on Every page, Opera doesn't show it at all, and webkit browsers only show it on the first page.

small test file:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>print css test by mtness</title>
     <style type="text/css">
     @media print {
      #watermark { 
       display: block;
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       z-index: 5;
      }
    
      p { 
       position: relative;
       top: 40pt;
       display: block;
       page-break-after: always;
       z-index: 0;
      }
     }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="watermark">AWESOME!</div>
     <p>page1</p>
     <p>page2</p>
     <p>page3</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

further resources might be found here:
http://room118solutions.com/2011/03/31/styling-print-headers-and-footers-with-css/
http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Printing_Headers
http://www.andypemberton.com/css/print-watermarks-with-css/

test page:
http://www.andypemberton.com/sandbox/watermark/

HTH.
Kind regards, mtness.

Comment: As of June 2015, this is still true for chrome.

Comment: See my answer below for an updated possible solution to this problem, @mtness

Comment: [Repeating table headers on printed pages](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826) was fixed on Chrome on Jun 5, 2016. I have the version 51.0.2704.103 on Mac OS X and it works.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: Apparently the bug has been fixed, so the library I share below may not be of much use anymore.

---

From all of my research, it is correct that there is no way to get `position: fixed` to work in Chrome. Here is a link to the [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303728) on the Chromium project page.

In the meantime, I have created [this open-source project that allows you to print headers and footers in Chrome](https://github.com/byuarchdi/print-headers-and-footers). It is early in development but it works, depending on the structure of your HTML layout:

It is a work-in-progress, and it relies heavily on the [CSS Regions Polyfill](https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-regions-polyfill). But I am using the techniques in this library to very good effect on a project at work.

Comment: It was fixed for a while, it seems to again be broken... at least in Android's webview.  Very strange.

Comment: In Chrome i always get 
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: document.getNamedFlow is not a function"
even in your examples

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished that using tables, but only for headers in chrome. I placed the repeating content on thead tag and the page content in tbody, so the browser interpreted correct.

However, I have encountered a bug in large contents HTML. In some cases, the content overlapped the header. In the date that I'm posting this, still not found a solution.

[When printing tables in Google Chrome, content overlaps header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555419/when-printing-tables-in-google-chrome-content-overlaps-header)

Answer (score 0):

```css
      thead.report-header {
   display: table-header-group;
}

tfoot.report_footer_Mh {
   display:table-footer-group;

}

   tabel.report-container {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

```html
<table class="report-container"  cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="790" align="center" background="" style="word-break: break-word">
  
  <!-- place the header part here-->
  <thead class="report_header_Mh">
    <tr>
      <th class="report_header_cell_Mh"> 
        <div class="header_info_Mh">
          
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- Header Ends here--> 
  
  <!-- Place the Main Content here-->
  <tbody class="report_content_Mh">
    <tr>
      <td class="report_content-cell_Mh">
      <div class="main_Mh">
       
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!-- Main Content ends here--> 
  
  <!--Place Footer content here-->
  <tfoot class="report_footer_Mh">
    <tr>
      <td class="report_footer-cell_Mh">
         <div class="footer_info_Mh">
          
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <!-- Footer Ends here-->
</table>

  

It worked for me try this way
```

Comment: Surrounding your code with an explanation would seriously improve your answer.

Comment: Your answer should be accompanied by some detail regarding how and why this works.