# Styles applied on header are not applied in print view

Tags: html, css

I want to print a table in chrome. The styles applied on table header are not being applied if a single row goes beyond the page and the header is repeated for it.

I have a very large value for the row and which made it go beyond a page and repeat the header in next page which doesn't have styles applied properly.

**Reference image:**
here background color is not applied for the next page header
[image]

code url: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iAKsBQ82J24r0TJaR9pMiFOtBNax7idq/view?usp=sharing

code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  color: red;
}
thead{
 color: red;
  background-color: blue;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
@media print{
thead{
 color: red !important;
  background-color: blue !important;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma
    </td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us your code pls

Comment: please just edit your answer and put there your code

Comment: the code is very big as it has a lot of test data.
will it be fine

Comment: just cut the test data

Comment: @Saravana no it didn't work if the second row has more data that goes beyond a page the style is not applied on the header then.

Comment: In my browser its working fine.

Comment: it feels like it is taking the background color of the 2nd row.
and as the first row doesn't have any background color default header background color is applied.

Comment: @Saravana i have updated the g drive url with the test data code where it doesn't work . can you please try with that and look into it

Comment: Which background color not appearing print preview. You mean blue background?

Comment: yes @Saravana ..

Comment: So you saying the second page blue bg header not working. Its like a fixed header for all page?

Comment: @Saravana , yes if we add more data in the row which has predefined styles and it goes beyond one page then header styles are not applied as depicted in the picture shown in question

Comment: Oh. How the `thead` repeated?

Comment: @Saravana `thead` has a default behavior to repeat itself in print view if the table goes beyond one page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192938/discussion-between-saravana-and-sashi-yadav).

Comment: @Sashiyadav Is it working?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's a Webkit/Chrome thing. It won't print the `thead` on each page. What you could do to achieve something like this is use page-break.

Page break does only work on block elements, so you should style your tr's accordingly.

```
tbody tr.head {
    page-break-before: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041761/print-a-header-for-every-page-in-google-chrome).

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    color: red;
    background-color: blue !important;
}

thead {
    color: red;
    background-color: blue !important;
}


tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
tbody tr.head {
    page-break-before: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
@media screen {
    tbody .head {
        display: none;
    }
    
    thead {
        color: red !important;
        background-color: blue !important;
    }
}
@media print {
    body {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma
    </td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: from the image, it seems that there is no background color in the second row, 

`tr:nth-child(even) { 
background-color: #dddddd; 
}` 

add this and try the background color will not be taken

Comment: @Sashiyadav I missed to remove the `}` from my css. Now the color working. check the updated one.

Comment: can you add the screenshot?

Comment: @Sashiyadav https://raw.githack.com/saravanasksp/tshirt/master/test.html

Comment: try having more data in the rows with a grey background. i.e (1st,3rd, etc)