# Watermark in HTML does not get printed in all pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add the below style for watermark.The watermark appears only in the first page when i try to print in Chrome.It works fine in firefox and IE.

```
<style type="text/css">
#watermark {
  color: #d0d0d0;
  font-size: 90pt;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>

<div id="watermark">
<p>WaterMark</p>
</div>
```

Is there any way which can be used to print the watermark in all pages

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gskzkb8g/

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is due to the `position:fixed`. The web has no native pagination, it's just one long page. Your `position fixed` will stay in the viewport when you scroll, but it only appears once when you print it in Chrome.

I think that what you're trying to do is not possible. Also look at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5886308/1236396

Comment: Yes.I found that its a known issue in Chrome..jus want to know the alternative... even @media print doesnt work

Comment: If you read the page I linked to you'll see that there is no solution. What you're trying to do isn't possible